# simplemodal iframe with close (X) icon?

Tags: simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal to display an external web page in an iframe. It works perfect. But I'm not sure my users are going to get the Esc key, or clicking outside the modal to close the modal window. I'd like to add a close icon "X" in the corner but i cant get it to appear. Is this supported for iframe? I could sure use and example. I'm trying to use what I see on simplemodal home but i'm not getting it.

Many Thanks for a simple modal,
Mike

Comment: It should just be a matter of getting the CSS correct to display the close image. See the "STYLING" section on http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ for the image and CSS to use.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I struggled with this for a few and then simply added $("#element-id") from your examples. 

from: $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="1000" style="border:0">', { closeHTML:"", opacity:80, overlayClose:true }); to: $("#element-id").modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="1000" style="border:0">', { closeHTML:"", opacity:80, overlayClose:true }); I get the look & feel but the iframe content is never loaded

Comment: If you can provide a more complete example and problem, perhaps I can help better.

Answer (score 3):

Getting rid of closeHTML:"" will fix the problem and the X image will work.